# Let user create a gallery and insert some pictures in it

Tags: wordpress

I was recently asked to create a page in an existing website that there will be some pre-uploaded pictures for each user and the user can create an album and select which of those pictures to be in it. Is there any plugin paid or free that will let me use that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear on the user experience you are going for, but we have a couple gallery options up on our site that we have had great success with. One is more of a grid gallery on pages, and is named simply 'Photo Gallery'. You can see it in action on our site: http://www.kaseykeownphotography.com/newborn/.

Another type of gallery we use is a slider. For that, we have been very happy with Slider WD. We used it twice in this blog post: http://www.kaseykeownphotography.com/a-mom-photographers-perspective-on-hiring-a-newborn-photographer/

Both of them work with an upload media library and can be configured for new purposes very easily. Good luck!